# Why does my glass reflection turn black when I play animation?

Tags: animation, 3d-view, glass, graph-editor, reflection

[image]

Trying this new glass tutorial by polyfjord.

Why does my glass animation suddenly turn all black when I am a couple of frames into the animation, does this has to do with my drivers??

[image]

Comment: i just tested it...i never see "all black" so i just can assume it's your graphic driver....did u try updating? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmZ08.jpg

Comment: Hey Chris, it usually happens only in the viewport, the render animation works fine, can it be just only a blender glitch??